# What is the first value $n$ such that $x^n$ outgrows $x!$? $n$ is a real number.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> What is the first value $n$ such that $x^n$ outgrows $x!$? $n$ is a real number.

Just curious as to what the approach would be to solving this problem. Aside from utilizing graphs like desmos of course, what is the algebraic way to solve this? I am sorry if this is a silly or easy question!

Comment: there is no such $n$?

Comment: n=infinity? There’s really no such n lol

Comment: $x!>(x/\mathrm{e})^x$ for all $x\ge 1$.

Comment: If you consider factorials as a continuous function, consider Stirling's approximation

Comment: $x^n = x!$ if $n = \log_x(x!) = \ln(x!)/\ln(x)$.  If $x > 1$, $x^n > x!$ if $n > \log_x(x!)$, but there isn't a "first" real $n$ for which this is the case.  Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: $x!$ grows exponential and therefore beats every power $x^n$ for $x\to\infty$

Comment: I believe the question is, for a **fixed** value of $x$, what is the first $n$ such that $x^n>\Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite I don't recall ever seeing the word "outgrows" used that way. But let's ask.

Comment: Do you mean that you will choose a particular $x$, and the for that $x$ (and only that $x$) you want the least $n$ such that $x^n\geq x!$? Or do you mean that you want to find a single smallest value $n$ such that $x!=o(x^n)$, that is, for large enough $x$ every increase in $x$ makes $x^n$ increase more than $x!$?

Answer (score 2):

Say that, in the real domain, you look for $a$ such that
$$x^a \geq x!=\Gamma(x+1)$$ Taking logarithms and using Stirling approximation
$$a=\frac{\log (\Gamma (x+1))}{\log (x)}$$ $$a=\frac 12+x-\frac{2 x-\log (2 \pi )}{2 \log (x)}+\frac{1}{12 x \log (x)} +O\left(\frac{1}{x^3\log(x)}\right)$$ Trying for $x=123.456$, this gives
$a=\color{red}{98.511789618}82$ while the exact solution, given by Newton method, is $98.51178961852$.

Comment: Finally someone who understood the question.

Comment: Cutting off the approximation at $O(x^{-1})$ still gives the quite accurate $98.51165$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such $n$. Suppose that, contrarily, we had had a candidate such $n$. Then $x^{n-1}$ does not outgrow $x!$ but $x^n$ does. This means that, for all sufficiently large $x$, say $x>x_0$, we have $x^{n-1}<x!< x^n$. To violate the latter constraints it is sufficient to violate the last one. Indeed, taking $x=x_0+2n$ will do the job, because then
$$x!=x_0!\cdot(x_0+1)\cdots(x_0+n)\cdot(x_0+n+1)\cdots(x_0+n+n).$$
Now multiply the final $n$ factors of this product pairwise with the previous $n$ factors in reverse order to get
$$x!=x_0!\prod_{k=1}^n[(x_0+k)(x_0+2n-k+1)].$$
The $k$th factor in the right-hand product, $(x_0+k)(x_0+2n-k+1)$, may be rewritten as
$$x_0(x_0+2n+1)+k(n-k+1),$$
which clearly exceeds $x=x_0+2n$. Consequently the product for $x!$ exceeds $x^n$.